# Java Graphics2D drawRect throw "sg2d.loops" is null

Tags: java, awt, bufferedimage, graphics2d

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read field "fillParallelogramLoop" because "sg2d.loops" is null
        at java.desktop/sun.java2d.pipe.LoopPipe.fillParallelogram(LoopPipe.java:355)
        at java.desktop/sun.java2d.pipe.PixelToParallelogramConverter.drawGeneralLine(PixelToParallelogramConverter.java:287)
        at java.desktop/sun.java2d.pipe.PixelToParallelogramConverter.drawLine(PixelToParallelogramConverter.java:80)
        at java.desktop/sun.java2d.pipe.PixelToParallelogramConverter.drawRect(PixelToParallelogramConverter.java:103)
        at java.desktop/sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawRect(SunGraphics2D.java:2410)
```

I just used Graphics2D to draw something on the BufferedImage.

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I believe this is a Java bug, and needs to be reported (along with the code necessary to reproduce it) to the OpenJDK project.

Comment: Are you modifying the BufferedImage with multiple threads?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem through the synchronous lock.

Comment: You should probably not draw to a `Graphics2D` from multiple threads in the first place...